# Primefaces - Dialog Framework - p:confirm not opening

Tags: primefaces, dialog

**Primefaces** (5.2, Mojarra 2.2.13) inside **Dialog Framework** is not opening a `<p:confirm>`-MessageBox.

I have delete icons in a datatable as a `<p:commandLink>` per row inside a Dialog.
I want to have a user confirmation to delete every row.

Following code works as expected in a `<p:dialog>` but not using Dialog Framework. Dialog Framework blocks the click on the delete icon or in other words: shows the confirm box invisible and answers NO.

```
<p:dataTable id="idTblMfc" value="#{bnMfcs.rows}" var="ORow" editable="true" ...>
    ... Columns ...
    <p:column>
        <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" title="#{msg.TXT_DELETE}" actionListener="#{bnMfcs.doDelete(ORow)}" update="idTblMfc">
            <p:confirm header="#{msg.TXT_DELETE}" message="#{msg.PRM_DEL_CONT_MARKED}" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
        </p:commandLink>                
    </p:column>
```

I tried the same with `<p:confirmDialog>` instead of `<p:confirm>` with the same result. OK, I found the tiny difference that `<p:confirmDialog>` doesn't block the delete icon click but also does not appear.

The rest of the dialog and the datatable works as expected even with message boxen shown with `showMessageInDialog(...)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the showcase (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml), you need both `p:confirm` (where you need confirmation) and `p:confirmDialog` (which defines how the dialog looks like).

Also make sure that you are in a `h:form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

The documentation makes not clear that `<p:confirmDialog>` is mandatory. I had one on my main page and the page using Dialog Framework had not.